# Why is this choose-when-test always true?

Tags: xslt, saxon

In an XSLT file I have defined a function

```
<xsl:function name="my:isValidDate">
    <xsl:param name="orgDate" />

    <xsl:value-of select="boolean(string-length($orgDate)=10)" />
</xsl:function>
```

to test whether a date string has a valid length.
When I use this function

```
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="my:isValidDate(ValidFrom)">
                <xsl:call-template name="formatDate"><xsl:with-param name="orgDate" select="ValidFrom"></xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            ...
        </xsl:choose>
```

it seems to always be true; even empty tags like `<ValidFrom />` pass the test and result in strange outputs, as the template must not be called on empty or invalid date strings. When I output `ValidFrom` for debugging issues, it is empty as expected. I also tried variants like `string-length($orgDate)=10` or `<xsl:value-of select="boolean($orgDate!='')" />` in the function, but nothing seems to work.
What am I missing?

EDIT: This condition is correctly evaluated, when I inline the function?!

Comment: Please show a [complete input sample and a complete stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can try to reproduce the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `<xsl:value-of select="boolean(string-length($orgDate)=10)" />` creates a text node with a string of the boolean value, to return a boolean value use `<xsl:sequence select="string-length($orgDate)=10" />`.